# Getting system.formatexception

Tags: c#, datetime

i m getting an error that
String was not recognized as a valid Date Time.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormateException: String was not recognized
>   as a valid Date Time.

Here is the place where I get the exception:

```
string validFrom="dd/MM/yyyy";
    {
        lstExchangeRates.Add(new KangoGiftRepository.Orm.ExchangeRate(1, cell.Value.ToString(), decimal.Parse(importSheet.Cells[startRow, 2].Value.ToString()), DateTime.ParseExact(validFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)));
        startRow++; cell = importSheet.Cells[startRow, 1];
        valid = cell?.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString().Length == 3;
    }
```

Comment: this is  the code where i m  getting this error

Comment: When you got the exception? please share the code

Comment: {
                    lstExchangeRates.Add(new KangoGiftRepository.Orm.ExchangeRate(1, cell.Value.ToString(),
                        decimal.Parse(importSheet.Cells[startRow, 2].Value.ToString()),  DateTime.ParseExact(validFrom,"dd/MM/yyyy",null)));
                    startRow++;
                    cell = importSheet.Cells[startRow, 1];
                    valid = cell?.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString().Length == 3;

                }

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of pasting code into comments.

Comment: what is the value for `validFrom` ?

Comment: @un-lucky -:string validFrom="dd/MM/yyyy";

Comment: if I'M passing Date like 23/03/2017 in place of dd/MM/yyyy than i never get any exception

Comment: See the [Documentation of DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx), the first parameter should be a string representation of a date and time

Comment: update the question with the code rather than putting it as a comment....

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because your string is not in a valid date format.

In your code sample, `validFrom` should be the actual value, not the date format string. You're getting the error because 'dd/MM/YYYY' cannot be parsed into 'dd/MM/yyyy'. '23/10/2016' can be parsed into 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

Here is a code snippet to parse dates:

```
  string[] dateValues = { "30-12-2011", "12-30-2011", 
                          "30-12-11", "12-30-11" };
  string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";
  DateTime parsedDate;

  foreach (var dateValue in dateValues) {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, 
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d}.", 
                          dateValue, parsedDate);
     else
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.", 
                          dateValue);
  }
```

To learn more about parsing dates, visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

To learn about valid format strings visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx